# How to build a site that can run android apps like Android Device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just want to know how can I make an Android Emulator that works in my Website. Ok, if I cannot explain correctly then you can check this site. This site provide online android emulator.
https://www.manymo.com/

I just want to build site like this, just for fun & Knowledge (coz I'm Free these days :P).
But I have no idea from where I should start. I have good knowledge of web development. But just want a guide to achieve this. 
I have search on Google & here also but all I get just name of other sites that provide this type of online services.

I just want a guide, what should can I do & what I need to learn extra....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are missing an API key. You need to get it from the developer console in order to use the places API.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places
```

And you are google.maps.event.addDomListener which when called google isn't defined at that instance and your autocomplete fails.
Here is an example to get you started with google places autocomplete API

```
<input id="search-text-field" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
   var input = document.getElementById('search-text-field');
   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
</script>
```

Replace YOUR_API_KEY with your api key

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the map first, and then add the input box as the control on the map.
Check this example for detailed info:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox